# Normalize Prometheus metrics over sampling interval

Tags: prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch, promql

From [cloudwatch-exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/cloudwatch_exporter) I get some gauges that provide stats like disk OPs performed or network packets transmitted between data points. What I need to achieve is to normalize these metrics by the sampling interval in order to get an approximation of the rate.

The problem is I can't simply divide the instant vector by a hardcoded interval value, since CloudWatch can be configured to count either over 1-minute or 5-minute bins. So, the Prometheus query has to be smart enough to be "self-normalizing".

The best solution I found so far is to exploit `count_over_time` to get the average interval over a range. I'm pretty confident it covers most CloudWatch configurations, but the problem is that it gets inaccurate near the end of the time-series.

```
aws_ec2_metric * count_over_time(aws_ec2_metric[300s]) / 300
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like `sum_over_time(aws_ec2_metric[300s]) / 300`. It will sum up all the values over the given time range (300s) and then calculate the average per-second rate by dividing the resulting value by 300.

Comment: FYI, VictoriaMetrics provides  `rate_over_sum(m[d])` function, which performs similar calculations to `sum_over_time(m[d]) / d`, but provides more accurate results and properly handles corner cases when `[d]` interval contains small number of raw data points. See more info at [MetricsQL docs](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html).


Disclaimer: I'm core developer at VictoriaMetrics.